# List positioning being uncooperative

Tags: html, css, list, position

Once again, lists are boggling my mind.

```
<div id="headbottom">
            <ul id="headnavbutton">
                <li id="button1" class="headnavbutton"></li>
                <li id="button2" class="headnavbutton"></li>
            </ul>   
 </div>
```

CSS:

```css
#headbottom{position:relative;width:960px;height:29px;margin:auto;bottom:10px;}
#headnavbutton{float:right;height:100%;width:250px;padding:0;}
.headnavbutton{float:right;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding-top:0px;list-style:none;}
#button1 {width:100px;height:100%;background:url(../images/headnavbutton.gif);}
#button2 {width:100px;height:100%;background:url(../images/headnavbutton.gif);}
```

Looks quite sweet and simple, you may say. But the for some reason unbeknownst to me, the list is pushed down out of the parent div.

Here is a JSfiddle: it's not accurate but it's a good representation for what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/WXbbj/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now define margin in your div **headnavbutton** as like this

```
#headnavbutton {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh god, I tried everything except this. I am an idiot. THANK YOU!